# Retrieve items from content type

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I have the following setup:

```
                    Root 
      Subsite1              Subsite2
        list1                 list2
    content type: News   content type: News
```

How can I retrieve the list items from the subsites and display them on my rootsite?

I was thinking to retrieve the content type and then retrieve the items?

Comment: Try to use SPSiteDataQuery http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For this process you should be using Search Results Webpart or retreiving Search Results from the Rest API. In 2013, you can focus on a content type, a list or anything you like. This will let you filter by the sites you want as well, to include any subsite or all subsites that the user has access to. This will also automatically trim the results for you.